# Flutter Chat show time by send message

Tags: firebase, flutter, chat, message

In my App I create a chat. This is my messageTile. Does anyone know how I can add a another text to this Container? Because this text should be the time when the user sends the message.

```
class MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool sendByMe;
  final int time;

  MessageTile({@required this.message, @required this.sendByMe, @required this.time});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 3,
          bottom: 3,
          left: sendByMe ? 0 : 24,
          right: sendByMe ? 24 : 0),
      alignment: sendByMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        margin: sendByMe
            ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 30)
            : EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 17, bottom: 17, left: 20, right: 20),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: sendByMe ? BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(9),
            ) :
            BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(9),
                topRight: Radius.circular(9),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(9)),
           color: sendByMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.white
        ),
        child: Text(message,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                fontSize: 9.0,),),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap in a column or row depending on your layout. The text should simply be `DateTime.now().toString()`.